# using BeautifulSoup and web scraping to automate web form fill outs

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup(or another web scraping API) to automate web forms.  For example, on the login page of Facebook there is also a registration form so lets say i want to fill out this form through automation.  So i would need to be able to find the relevant html tags(such as the inputs for first name, last name, etc) and then i would want to take all of that input and push a request to Facebook to make that account, how would this be done?

Comment: Try **Selenium**.  https://www.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 0):

Even I am beginner in the scraping, I was facing these problems too. To carry out basic scraping operations we can use beautiful soup. While learning more about scraping I came across "Scrapy" tool. We can use Scrapy for many more functionality like you specified. Try out [Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) here. This is recommended by many professional web **scraper** .